# How to disable past dates or future dates in Calendar in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I'm doing a sample on DatePicker and in this i want to disable past dates or future dates in codenameone.

code:

```
Picker datePicker = new Picker();
datePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
datePicker.setDate(new Date());
```

how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At this time the picker API just doesn't support this since it's implemented natively. You can use the `Calendar` API or similar to achieve such functionality.

Comment: thanks for reply.. can you provide some code please? because some methods in Calendar while run the app in simulator working fine but while generating build it showing error(for ex: Calendar.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) ..

Comment: I was referring to `com.codename1.ui.Calendar` not `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: i have tried that but in that Component "setYearRange()" method is available but showing all months of the current year(For example i have set the year range from 2017 to 2011 but 2017 also it showing all months i want to show from current month).. is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can derive calendar and override create day and similar methods meant to customize the behavior of the UI.

Comment: sorry shai i've tried but i'm unable to do it. is there any alternative way?

Comment: Just add validation to the field, there is no simpler way to do that as we don't have such an API builtin